# Search by the combination of multiple parameters via Native Query

Tags: java, jpa, nativequery

I'm currently working on a fetaure that will allow the system to search public services receipts by the combination of 6 parameters which can be null meaning that receipts shouldn't be filtered by this parameter:  accountNumber, amountRangeMin, amountRangeMax, dateRangeMin, dateRangeMax,  publicServiceId. However making a method for each combination of the parameters is not an option, I'm thinking that there must be a better way, at first my approach was as following:

On my Service I have this method:

```
public Map<String,Object> findPublicServiceReceiptsByParams(Integer accountNumber, BigDecimal amountRangeMin,
        BigDecimal amountRangeMax, LocalDate dateRangeMin, LocalDate dateRangeMax, Integer publicServiceId) {
    Map<String,Object> publicServiceReceipts = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    String accountNumberFilter = !(accountNumber==null) ? accountNumber.toString() : "AccountNumberTableName";
    String amountRangeMinFilter = !(amountRangeMin==null) ? amountRangeMin.toString() : "table.AmountColumnName";
    String amountRangeMaxFilter = !(amountRangeMax==null) ? amountRangeMax.toString() : "table.AmountColumnName";
    String dateRangeMinFilter = !(dateRangeMin==null) ? dateRangeMin.toString() : "Table.ReceiptCreationDateColumn";
    String dateRangeMaxFilter = !(dateRangeMax==null) ? dateRangeMax.toString() : "Table.ReceiptCreationDateColumn";
    String publicServiceIdFilter = !(publicServiceId==null) ? publicServiceId.toString() : "table.publicServiceIdColumn";
    publicServiceReceipts = publicServiceReceiptRepository.findPublicServiceReceiptsByParams(accountNumberFilter,
            amountRangeMinFilter, amountRangeMaxFilter, dateRangeMinFilter, dateRangeMaxFilter,
            publicServiceIdFilter);
    return publicServiceReceipts;
}
```

And then in my repository I had:

```
final static String FIND_PUBLIC_SERVICES_BY_ARGS = "Select (Insert whatever logic should go in here to select columns from receipts the where clause is the one that matters)"
        + "    WHERE ACT.ACT_AccountNumber=:accountNumberFilter\n"
        + "      AND PSE.PSE_Id=:publicServiceIdFilter\n"
        + "      AND PSR.PSR_CreateDate BETWEEN :dateRangeMinFilter AND :dateRangeMaxFilter\n"
        + "      AND PSR.PSR_Amount BETWEEN :amountRangeMinFilter AND :amountRangeMaxFilter\n"
        + " order by PSR.PSR_CreateDate desc";

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = FIND_PUBLIC_SERVICES_BY_ARGS)
Map<String, Object> findPublicServiceReceiptsByParams(@Param("accountNumberFilter") String accountNumberFilter,
        @Param("amountRangeMinFilter") String amountRangeMinFilter,
        @Param("amountRangeMaxFilter") String amountRangeMaxFilter,
        @Param("dateRangeMinFilter") String dateRangeMinFilter,
        @Param("dateRangeMaxFilter") String dateRangeMaxFilter,
        @Param("publicServiceIdFilter") String publicServiceIdFilter);
```

}

My reasoning was that if a parameter was null meant that whoever consumed the Web Service is not interested in that paramater so if that happens I set that variable as the Column Name so that it wouldn't affect in the WHERE clause and in theory make it simpler, but what I found was that It would send the names as Strings so it wouldn't be recognized as an sql statement which was the flaw in my thinking and as I said there must be another way other than writing each method for each combination, I appreciate any help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [Criteria API](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria), which was designed for creating dynamic queries. Named queries aren't really meant to be used in this case.
With it you can do something like this:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

List<YourEntity> method(String argument) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<YourEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(YourEntity.class);
    Root<YourEntity> root = cq.from(YourEntity.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if (argument == null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("yourAttribute"), argument);
    }
    // rest of your logic goes here

    cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: That sounds nice, thanks! however since no one seemed to answer I found a workarround to your approach idk if it is a better one tho, I don't think so since yours look very clean, I'll add my approach as and answer to this question so you can check it out and give me some feedback, anyway thanks for the answer I didn't even know that API existed and it seems pretty usefull

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this, I did it like this (I'm going to show only the native Query since it's the inly thing that i changed):

```
DECLARE  @actNum varchar(50),@crdNum varchar(50),@pseId varchar(50),@dateMin varchar(50),@dateMax varchar(50),@amountMin varchar(50),@amountMax varchar(50)
SET @actNum = :actNum
SET @crdNum = :crdNum 
SET @pseId =  :pseId 
SET @dateMin = :dateMin 
SET @dateMax = :dateMax 
SET @amountMin = :amountMin 
SET @amountMax = :amountMax 
--Whatever Select with joins statement
                   WHERE ACT.ACT_AccountNumber = CASE WHEN @actNum = 'N/A' 
                                             THEN ACT.ACT_AccountNumber 
                                             ELSE @actNum END
                 AND CRD_CardNumber = CASE WHEN @crdNum = 'N/A' 
                                      THEN CRD_CardNumber 
                                      ELSE @crdNum END
                 AND PSE.PSE_Id= CASE WHEN @pseId = 'N/A' 
                                 THEN PSE.PSE_Id 
                                 ELSE @pseId END
                 AND PSR.PSR_CreateDate >= CASE WHEN @dateMin = 'N/A' 
                                                THEN PSR.PSR_CreateDate 
                                                ELSE @dateMin END 
                                        AND PSR.PSR_CreateDate <= CASE WHEN @dateMax = 'N/A' 
                                            THEN PSR.PSR_CreateDate 
                                            ELSE @dateMax END
                 AND PSR.PSR_Amount BETWEEN CASE WHEN @amountMin = 'N/A' 
                                            THEN PSR.PSR_Amount 
                                            ELSE @amountMin END 
                                    AND CASE WHEN @amountMax = 'N/A' 
                                        THEN PSR.PSR_Amount 
                                        ELSE @amountMax END 
            ORDER BY PSR.PSR_CreateDate DESC
```

The backend will send the parameters as either "N/A" (if it shouldn't be used to filter data) or the actual value, this worked fine for me!

Comment: The problem with this code is, that it might become hard to maintain if the logic grows more complex. Also, whoever calls this method must know to send the value 'N/A', if it isn't includede in the query. Simply omitting the value would be easier to understand. I don't know if there are any performance differences, you would have to measure this. However, if the code works in your case, it won't become much more complicated and the number of people interacting with your code isn't too high, you can just leave it as it is.